# modopt and .NET reflection

Tags: .net, reflection, c++-cli

I have a CLI/C++ interface that I want to examine via .NET Reflection.  Here's the function signature in the source code:

```
class ClassA;
template<typename _Type> class ClassTempA;

public interface class Test : BaseFunc {
public:
    ClassTempA<int>& SomeFunc2(ClassA inst) = 0;
};
```

Here's what the function looks like when examined in .NET Reflector:

```
unsafe ClassTempA<int>* modopt(IsImplicitlyDereferenced) SomeFunc2(ClassA inst);
```

Is there a way to get at the modopt attributes via .NET reflection, or do I have to use the Metadata
Unmanaged API?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can get the `modopt` and `modreq` info from `System.Reflection` by calling [`ParameterInfo::GetOptionalCustomModifiers()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.parameterinfo.getoptionalcustommodifiers.aspx) and [`ParameterInfo::GetRequiredCustomModifiers()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.parameterinfo.getrequiredcustommodifiers.aspx), respectively.  To illustrate with your types, see the following.

```
class ClassA;
template<typename _Type> class ClassTempA;

public interface class Test : BaseFunc {
public:
    ClassTempA<int>& SomeFunc2(ClassA inst) = 0;
};

array<Type^>^ GetModifiers()
{
    MethodInfo^ SomeFunc2 = Test::typeid->GetMethod("SomeFunc2");
    return method->ReturnParameter->GetOptionalCustomModifiers();
}
```