# Build issue with c# code - CS0012 - IsLongModifier

Tags: c#

I have a very simple piece of code which on compilation gives me the below error

> Error CS0012  The type 'IsLongModifier' is defined in an assembly that
>   is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly
>   'Microsoft.VisualC, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.

Below is the relevant portion of the code

```
grid.get_NumericalCell(rowIndex, "Bench2");
```

I get a red squiggly over the get_NumericalCell function call.

The method is available from a third party library which is implemented in C++/C#. Below is the signature of the method

```
double get_NumericalCell(int rowIndex, string columnName);
```

If I add a reference to Microsoft.VisualC, then the error disappears.

The reference documentation on [IsLongModifier class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualc.islongmodifier(v=vs.110).aspx) was not much helpful in explaining why I am facing this issue.

Can someone explain why I need a reference to Microsoft.VisualC.IsLongModifier - I don't see where I am referring to it in my code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's likely that the third-party library has a reference to `Microsoft.VisualC`.

The signature for `get_NumericalCell()` might have had an override in C++ that looked like this:

```
__gc class Grid 
{
   double get_NumericalCell(int i, string columnName) {}
   double get_NumericalCell(long l, string columnName) {}
};
```

That would be compiled to IL that looked like this:

```
[...] float64 get_NumericalCell(int32 i, ...) [...]
[...] float64 get_NumericalCell(int32 modopt([Microsoft.VisualC]Microsoft.VisualC.IsLongModifier) l, ...) [...]
```

The optional modifier, `IsLongModifier`, is added to differentiate the two signatures, which would otherwise be identical. This hides the method in C# but the compiler might still need a reference to `Microsoft.VisualC`. You can check with reflection via the [`GetOptionalCustomModifiers()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.parameterinfo.getoptionalcustommodifiers.aspx) method.

Comment: What I do not follow, is why would I get a compile time failure if a third-party library has a reference to another library

Comment: A reference to the `IsLongModifier` type might somehow be exposed by the call to `get_NumericalCell()`

Comment: Can you add  some examples to show how that can happen, so I understand better

Comment: @Vikhram I added an example

Answer (score 2):

If you examine the third party assembly with a decompiler (ILDasm, ILSpy, .NET Reflector, dotPeek etc.), you'll see that the parameters of the method you're calling are decorated, at the IL level, with modifiers (`modopt`) of the type the compiler's complaining about (you can also write code to inspect them yourself: [modopt and .NET reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/408028/modopt-and-net-reflection)). The compiler needs the reference at compile time to reason about the code to emit, the same way it sometimes complains about the lack of reference to the assembly with a base type of a type you're directly using, even though your compiled assembly does not end up referencing the "extra" assembly itself.

Comment: The `grid` variable is a reference to an interface, and the interface method is not decorated. I tried to find out the implementation of it and that too does not seem to be decorated

Comment: Oh. If you want to get to the bottom of this, you can decompile the entire third party assembly and search it for occurrences of the offending type.

Comment: It is C#/C++, so I cannot decompile all pieces